# How to split values present in column in dataframe into multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the values present in the column into different column like  this using python script or function applying onto dataframe

```
  Number |   0|  1|  2|  3
 78797071|  78| 79| 70| 71
```

I am able to do so by using this

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df["Number"].astype(str).str.findall("..").values.tolist()).add_prefix('DIV')).fillna("00")
```

but i dont want to use above this i want a function and use apply() function on dataframe to use that python script function is it possible to do so ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to split the values as you would in a CSV, the delimiter being `|`? So something like this `numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in s.split("|")]`

Comment: Pleas share a sample of the data

Comment: the number column contain values like this 78797071  which will be split into 4 new column and each column contain two values i.e. 78 in one column  79 in another column  followed by this , there is no dilimiter its just representation

Answer (score 0):

If the columns always contains 8 digit numbers, you could do:

```
result = df.Number.astype(str).str.extract('(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', expand=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
    0   1   2   3
0  78  79  70  71
```

Comment: i dont want to use builtin function rather that i want to create a script and apply() that over a df

Comment: @PURU you can put that in a function that returns a DataFrame. Also want do you mean by create a script?

Comment: i mean by script is not using builtin function create your own function and then use apply() methon on it

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is what you need (it is basically what you have but as a function that you could apply on any dataframe)

```
def func(df):
    global df1
    f = (pd.DataFrame(df["Number"].astype(str).str.findall("..").values.tolist()).add_prefix('DIV'))
    df1=df.join(f).fillna("00")
    return df1

func(df)
```

You can call the function on any `df`

**Output**

```
df1
     Number     0   1   2   3   DIV0    DIV1    DIV2    DIV3
0   78797071    78  79  70  71  78       79     70       71
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha so **if** I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```py
from textwrap import wrap

number = 78797071

numbers = [int(n) for n in wrap(str(number), 2)]  # outputs a list [78, 79, 70, 71]
```